# Time Evolution of a Spin State

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am stuck at paragraph 2.1.5 of Modern Quantum Mechanics - Sakurai

We have a simple system - spin $\frac{1}{2}$ system subjected to an external magnetic field $\mathbf{B}=(0,0,B)$. The time-evolution operator is calculated to be $$\mathcal{U} (t,0)=\exp{\Big(\frac{-i\omega S_zt}{\hbar}\Big)}$$

If we apply this time-evolution operator to some arbitrary state $|\alpha \rangle = c_{+}|+\rangle + c_{-}|-\rangle$, we see that the state evolves to $$|\alpha;t\rangle = c_{+} \exp{\big(\frac{-i\omega t}{2}\big)} |+\rangle + c_{-} \exp{\big(\frac{i\omega t}{2}\big)} |-\rangle$$

Now, let the initial state of the system be $S_{x}^{+} = |S_x;+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |+\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |-\rangle$ at time $t=0$. Using the above, we can see that after time $t$, this state will evolve to $$|S_x^{+};t\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\exp{\big(\frac{-i \omega t}{2}\big)}|+\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\exp{\big(\frac{i \omega t}{2}\big)}|-\rangle$$

After this, they've calculated the probability of the system which was initially in $S_{x}^{+}$ to be found in $S_{x}^{+}$ and also the probability of the same initial system to be found in $S_{x}^{-}$ as $|\langle S_{x};+ | {S_x^{+};t}\rangle|^2$ and $|\langle S_{x};- | {S_x^{+};t}\rangle|^2$  respectively.

How I understood this is $|\langle S_{x};+ | {S_x^{+};t}\rangle|^2$ is the probability that the state $|S_x^{+};t\rangle$ upon measurement collapses to $S_{x}^{+}$ and $|\langle S_{x};- | {S_x^{+};t}\rangle|^2$ is the probability that the state $|S_x^{+};t\rangle$ upon measurement collapses to $S_{x}^{-}$. Do I understand this correctly? or are they simply calculating the transition probability?

If yes, then isn't it true that a state can only collapse to one of its basis and not to any arbitrary state? If that is true, then how can $|S_x^{+};t\rangle$ collapse to $S_{x}^{+}$ and same with the other case?

Comment: Isn't transition probability from $|S_{x};+\rangle$ to $|S_{x};-\rangle$, the same as the probability for that very state to collapse to $|S_{x};-\rangle$ upon measurement at time t ?

Comment: The collapse of a wave function to a state depends on your measurement apparatus. For example, the act of measurement is equivalent to projecting the state your system onto a particular basis.

Answer (score 0):

> How I understood this is $|⟨_;+|^+_;⟩|^2$
> is the probability that the state $|^+_;⟩$
> upon measurement collapses to $^+_$
> and $|⟨_;−|^+_;⟩|^2$
> is the probability that the state $|^+_;⟩$
> upon measurement collapses to $^−_$
> . Do I understand this correctly? or are they simply calculating the transition probability?

Your understanding is correct.

> If yes, then isn't it true that a state can only collapse to one of its eigenstates and not to any arbitrary state? If that is true, then how can $|^+_;⟩$
> collapse to $^+_$
> and same with the other case?

A state doesn't have eigenstates. An $\textbf{operator}$ has eigenstates. When you measure an observable, the state collapses to one of the eigenstates of the corresponding operator. For example, the operator which represents the $x$-component of the spin has eigenstates $|S_x;+\rangle$ and $|S_x;-\rangle$. So when you measure the $x$-component of the spin (on any arbitrary state), the state collapses to one of these eigenstates.

Notice the time-evolved state in the OP, $|S_x^+;t\rangle$, is generally not an eigenstate of the operator $S_x$. Measuring the spin in the $x$-direction causes the time-evolved state to collapse to one of these eigenstates with probabilities given in the OP.

Comment: So, there were two places where I messed up. 

1. I was thinking along the lines that a state can only collapse to one of its basis states (which I incorrectly wrote as eigenstates). This is not true. 

2. I did talk about measurement but missed with what observable are we measuring it. We measure it with $S_x$ and because $S_x^{+}$ and $S_x^{-}$ are the two eigenstates of $S_x$, it collapses to either one of them with certain probability. It all makes sense now. Thank you so much! :)